# Why react 'key' props doesn't work for my below case?

Tags: react-hooks

I used both (item.id and index) to show unique "key" but it's never working shows those warning (Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop). Also all my server get disconnected after a while. So, How do I solve both issue? here is my code..

```
let details = [
   { id: 0, Name: "Pervej", Age: 20 },
   { id: 1, Name: "Hossain", Age: 21 },
];

const [array, SetArray] = useState(details);

const ClearClick = () => {
  SetArray([]);
};

<div className="box">
  {array.map((item, index) => {
    return (
     <>
      <h2 key={item.id}>
          Name: {item.Name} , Age: {item.Age},
      </h2>
     </>
   );
 })}
<button type="button" onClick={ClearClick}>
          Clear
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `key` should be on the top most element. You can't set `props` for the empty shorthand `<>`. But you can set it to `<React.Fragment>`.

Watch out when using `index` as `keys`, though (your ids look indexes). Read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

So, your code should be:

```
<div className="box">
  {array.map((item, index) => {
    return (
     <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
       <h2>
          Name: {item.Name} , Age: {item.Age},
       </h2>
     </React.Fragment>
   );
 })}
```